# Mutual Authentication in Tornado with self signed certificates

Tags: tornado, self-signed, mutual-authentication

Going through the Tornado docs, I can't seem to find a treatment about 
two way SSL authentication. Currently the codes looks something like this using self-signed certificates:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

class fooHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      #Do Something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/foo/", fooHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options={
            "certfile": "./cert.pem",
            "keyfile": "./key.pem",
        })
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: [Origin-Bound Certificates: A Fresh Approach to Strong Client
Authentication for the Web](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final162.pdf) and [The Token Binding Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tokbind-protocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `verify_mode` of your `ssl.SSLContext`:

```
ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain("cert.pem", "key.pem")
# If your certs are not self-signed, load your CA certificates here.
#ssl_ctx.load_verify_locations("cacerts.pem")
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
http_server = HTTPServer(application, ssl_options=ssl_ctx)
```

Then you can use [`self.request.get_ssl_certificate`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html?highlight=httpserverrequest#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.get_ssl_certificate) to get the client's certificate.